# iptables command returns "No chain/target/match by that name."

Tags: linux, kernel, firewall, iptables, yocto

I'm using yocto linux and I've installed iptables and the corresponding linux drivers.

Everything works fine using commands like: `iptables -P INPUT DROP`.

What I want to do though is `iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT` or `iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT` but they return this error:

```
iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.
```

Maybe the problem is related to "-m" but `iptables -m state -h` correctly returns the helper.

These are the driver/module that I've enabled in my kernel:

```
CONFIG_NETFILTER=y
CONFIG_NF_MATCH_STATE=y
CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK=y
CONFIG_NF_TABLES=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XTABLES=y
CONFIG_IP_SET=y
CONFIG_IP_NF_IPTABLES=y
CONFIG_IP_NF_FILTER=y
CONFIG_IP_NF_MATCH_STATE=y
CONFIG_IP_NF_CONNTRACK=y
```

What do you guys suggest to do? Thanks

**EDIT**: solved by using menuconfig and adding all the required dependencies which are:

1. Networking options > Network packet filtering framework (Netfilter)
2. Networking options > IP: Netfilter Configuration

Comment: Maybe try to set options as modules "=m" instead of builtin "=y", then look if `nf_conntrack` module is loaded? Are you sure those options are applied ? (read options in `/proc/config.gz`)

Comment: I tried to set these options as modules this time but it got worse: I cannot use iptables at all since it returns  `can't initialize iptables table filter: iptables who?`. I also try to `modprobe ip_tables` but I get the same result as above. In /proc/config.gz I cannot see those options in the current configuration. What am I doing wrong in your opinion?

Comment: Where do you set those options in Yocto? Is it in [fragment files](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#creating-config-fragments)? Which kernel provider do you use?

Comment: I'm manually modifying my defconfig file

Comment: You should use fragments or override defconfig following [manual](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#changing-the-configuration)

Comment: So, I played a little bit with menuconfig, setted more options to built-in and now it's finally working. I have a couple of compiled drivers that are no more compatible with the kernel though... but that's another thing. Thanks @Nayfe